# overwriting the .htaccess file on Server

Tags: java, windows, apache, .htaccess, coldfusion

My `.htaccess` file contains url mappings and my script create these entries once a day.
As `.htaccess` is a hidden file on Server, when the script tries to overwrite this `.htaccess` file I get 
an error message `Access Denied`.

Is there a way to overwrite the file.

Comment: Server type (Windows or Unix)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the problem here is that you're on Windows, and Windows doesn't especially like filenames that begin with a dot (it thinks you're creating a file with an empty "name", and a "htaccess" extension).

The fastest solution might just be to change the name of the file that Apache's looking for to e.g. `htaccess.txt` using the `AccessFileName` [directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#accessfilename).

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the name starts with a `.` has nothing to do with the access permissions.

Check `ls -l /path/to/.htaccess` output for the `user:group` and permissions on the file, and make sure that your script executes with sufficient privileges to write the file. This might mean running your script in the `crontab(5)` of your webserver, or it might mean running `chown(1)` to change the owner to whoever should be running your script, or using `chown(1)` to change the *group* of the file to the *group* of the program, and then using `chmod(1)` to allow group-writes.

It depends upon what you really want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the file and let your script create it next time it runs (or force the generation). This way the user which runs the script will be the owner of the file, so it should work from then on.

Also check if your script can create files in that directory.